# How to create infinite router loop

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have to create screen with user profile, in which I have to be able to see users subscribed by him (and those which subscribed him). After clicking on one of them I have to move to its profile screen where I can see users subscribed by him etc. Also, when clicking back (either stack view arrow or Android back button) I have to go back screen by screen. How to achieve that? I tried couple things but nothing worked...

Those are routes I came up with:

```js
export const SubscribbedRouter = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Subscribbed: {
            screen: SubscribbedScreen
        }
    }
);

export const SubscribbedByRouter = createStackNavigator(
    {
        SubscribbedBy: {
            screen: SubscribbedByScreen
            }
        }
    }
);

export const ProfileSwitchRouter = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        SubscribbedRouter,
        SubscribbedByRouter
    }
);

export const ProfileRouter = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Profile: {
            screen: ProfileSettingsScreen
        },
        ProfileSwitch: {
            screen: ProfileSwitchRouter
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I wonder if you ever able to solve this. If so, can you share how?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use push instead of navigate

This allows you to express the intent to add another route regardless of the existing navigation history.

this.props.navigation.push('Details')

Each time you call push it will add a new route to the navigation stack. When you call navigate it first tries to find an existing route with that name, and only pushes a new route if there isn't yet one on the stack.

You can read more here 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html